# Universal link is not working in IOS 12.1?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I've created a demo project for enable universal link and followed all the below steps -

1. Enable the Associated domains in AppId
2. Edit provisioning profiles
3. In Project - Enable Associated domain and also add domain link (mobiledemo.socialengineaddons.com) , no any error is coming
4. Domain link is also show in seiosnativeapp.entitlements file
5. I manually added seiosnativeapp.entitlements file , in Copy Bundle Resources (Build Phases)
6. Handle link activity in AppDelegate (Swift 4.2 ,Xcode 10.1) -
   AppDelegate :

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity:
     NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping 
     ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

   ```
   print("Activity")
   if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
       let url = userActivity.webpageURL!
       print(url.absoluteString)

       //handle url and open whatever page you want to open.
   }

   window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
   let ViewController = UIViewController()
   window?.rootViewController = ViewController
   window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   return true
   ```

   }
7. My AppId and prefix both are same
8. Create a apple-app-site-association File and Placed in .well-known 
       folder :

   https://mobiledemo.socialengineaddons.com/.well-known/apple-app-site- 
     association
9. My domain name is also ssl certified and also i've use this command 
      to remove validator error -

   [Sign apple-app-site-association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843198/sign-apple-app-site-) 
      association

   sudo touch json.txt | openssl smime -sign -inkey myserver.key -signer 
     mobiledemo.socialengineaddons.com.crt -noattr -nodetach -outform DER

   > apple-app-site-association
10. Link Validator : Successfully validate domain 
    (mobiledemo.socialengineaddons.com)

    https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox
    https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com/

Note: When we place apple-app-site-association file on root , validator 
          gives error, so we placed this on .well-known folder
11. When i added my website link on Notes (IOS app) 
        https://mobiledemo.socialengineaddons.com and long press , it not 
        show any open to open in my app also when i click on this link 
        every-time it's open in safari instead of app
12. I've followed below reference Links :

```
    https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios- 
    79c4ee038272
    https://www.raywenderlich.com/6080-universal-links-make-the- 
    connection
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEXn7QIwPFo
```

13. It'll very help-full to me, if you provide any suggestions to 
        enable 
       universal link , Thanks In Advance 
       [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBTW.png
       [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/esB8f.png

```
   [1]: http://%20com.seao.seiosnativeapp
```

Comment: Where is applinks key in aasa file ?

Answer (score 1):

In Capabilities add app-links prefix and colon. applinks prefi is mandatory. So it would look like below.

applinks:mobiledemo.socialengineaddons.com